# Sensors are not function with ESP8266 WeMos-D1R2

Tags: esp8266, sensors, web-server, wires

I attached all sensor into the Wemos-D1 for uploading the sensor data to the server. but when I upload the data to the server, it connects to the server but cannot save the data into the database and after that send the second data to the server, it shows connections failed... besides, the sensor such as ultrasonic sensor and IR sensor cannot function.

here is the source code for connecting the sensor to the wemos. Not sure the connecting those sensors are correct or not to the wemos.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
//LiquidCrystal LCD(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
LiquidCrystal LCD(D0,D1, D5, D4, D3, D2);
const char* ssid     = "wifi username";
const char* password = "wifi password";
const char* host = "192.168.1.10";

#define in  D7 //7
#define out D8 //8
#define trigPin D2 //10
#define echoPin D3 //13
#define relay D2 //2
#define led D6 //6            //red color
#define led2 D0           //yellow color
#define led3 D1 //9           //green color

int count = 0;

int distanceCm;
long duration;

void IN()
{
  count++;
  LCD.clear();
  LCD.print("Number of Item:");
  LCD.setCursor(0, 1);
  LCD.print(count);
  delay(10);
  LCD.setCursor(3, 1);
  LCD.print(distanceCm);
  delay(10);
  LCD.setCursor(6, 1);
  LCD.print(" cm");
  if (distanceCm <= 3) {
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    LCD.setCursor(10, 1);
    LCD.print("Full");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }

  if (distanceCm > 3 && distanceCm <= 5) {
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    LCD.setCursor(10, 1);
    LCD.print("Enable");
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  }

  if (distanceCm > 5) {
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    LCD.setCursor(10, 1);
    LCD.print("Empty");
//    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
  } else {
//    digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
}

void OUT()
{
  count--;
  LCD.clear();
  LCD.print("Number of Item:");
  LCD.setCursor(0, 1);
  LCD.print(count);
  delay(10);
  LCD.setCursor(3, 1);
  LCD.print(distanceCm);
  LCD.setCursor(6, 1);
  LCD.print(" cm");
  if (distanceCm <= 3) {
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    LCD.setCursor(10, 1);
    LCD.print("Full");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }

  if (distanceCm > 3 && distanceCm <= 5) {
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    LCD.setCursor(10, 1);
    LCD.print("Enable");
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  }

  if (distanceCm > 5) {
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    LCD.setCursor(10, 1);
    LCD.print("Empty");
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);

  LCD.begin(16, 2);
  LCD.print("Item Counter");
  delay(2000);

  pinMode(in, INPUT);
  pinMode(out, INPUT);
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);

  LCD.clear();
  LCD.print("Item In Box:");
  LCD.setCursor(0, 1);
  LCD.print(count);
  // ESP.restart();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    // ESP.wdtFeed();
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

int value = 0;
void loop() {

  delay(0);
  delay(5000);
  ++value;

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(50);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distanceCm = duration * 0.034 / 2;

  //******************************************************//
  //IR Sensor Counting Object
  if (digitalRead(in) == HIGH && digitalRead(out) == LOW) {
    IN();
  }

  if (digitalRead(out) == HIGH && digitalRead(in) == LOW) {
    OUT();
  }

  if (count <= 0)
  {
    LCD.clear();
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
    LCD.clear();
    LCD.print("No Item in box");
    LCD.setCursor(0, 1);
    LCD.print("box is empty");
    delay(200);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
  }

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 8095;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
      delay(0);
    }
  }

  String IRCount, myDistance;
  IRCount = String(count);
  myDistance = String(distanceCm);
  // We now create a URI for the request
  String url = "/Registration/write_data.php";
  url += "?item=";
  url += IRCount;
  url += "&distance=";
  url += myDistance;

  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  int timeout = millis() + 5000;
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (timeout - millis() < 0) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while (client.available()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}
```

[image]

Anyone has the solutions please help me

Comment: is the LCD SPI? you use 4 pins D5/SCK, D6/MISO, D7/MOSI, D8/SS like it would be 10 different pins. how did you wire things?

Comment: LCD wire code is LCD(MISO, MOSI,D5, D4, D3, D2) which consists of 6pins for the LCD and then the IN and OUT pins are IR SENSOR PINS AND TRIG AND ECHO for the ultrasonic sensor pins but all of these sensors can’t work.

Comment: MISO is D6, MOSI id D7. why do you use SPI pin defines if it is not SPI?

Comment: MISO is the Wemos board pins... if I use the arduino board pins it wouldn’t work

Comment: Wemos has D0 to D8. MISO and MOSI are aliases to D6 and D7

Comment: But for what I attach  the MISO and MOSI pins are representing the D12 and D11

Comment: I have edited the pins based on just now u mention there are only D0 to D8 in wemos. So, I have edited the source code as above... but it shows this error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

Comment: but you how do you wire it if D2, D3 are for display and for ultrasonic sensor and relay at the same time? pins D3,  D4 and D8 are boot setup pins with pull-ups and pull-down (D8). this state must be preserved at boot. the wired devices must not pull-down D3 and D4 to LOW or set D8 HIGH before they are initialized in setup()

Comment: = = I have no idea already because I use the Arduino UNO board logic to wire it

Comment: Because i have 2 IR sensor, 1 ultrasonic sensor and LCD which must connect it to the Wemos board

Comment: use I2C LCD or don't use LCD but make a web page

Comment: make a web page?

Comment: you mean that if i dont use LCD then i have enough pins for me to connect ?

Comment: or display the data on the webpage that is what i want

Comment: I meant a local web page

Comment: Ya that what I going to do. Now For what I do is uploading this data into the php file and this php file will save it into the database. After that I use the webpage to read this data from the database and display it on the local webpage

Comment: Just for clarification, there are nine pins for me to attach the sensor (D0 -D8) in wemos. So if I attach the sensor to those pins (D0 -D8) so it can function and directly upload the data ?

Comment: yes. only test the sensors on different pins to find out what doesn't disturb D3, D4 and D8 at boot. and avoid D0 if you can. it is a little special too